# Trying to install Mullvad VPN on Manjaro ARM Laptop via yay and getting rust backtrace error

Tags: command, vpn, arm, panic, rust

Please help me solve this issue! I have already uninstalled rust but that did not solve the problem... Here is the code:

```
   error: failed to run custom build command for `libdbus-sys v0.2.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/flowet/.cache/yay/mullvad-vpn/src/mullvadvpn-app/target/release/build/libdbus-sys-2e5f442eec395f29/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Command { command: "\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"dbus-1\" \"dbus-1 >= 1.6\"", cause: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" } }', /home/flowet/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libdbus-sys-0.2.1/build.rs:6:70
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: There's no need to use their software: you could simply use the provided OpenVPN config files: https://mullvad.net/en/help/linux-openvpn-installation/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PKGBUILD of mullvad-vpn](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=mullvad-vpn#n14) the package is only made for x86_64 (not ARM CPUs) and probably nobody bothered to port it to ARM (yet)

but no worries, Mullvad has excellent help topics to use it's service by other means
by default the official App would use Wireguard, [here is the help site for Mullvad with Wireguard](https://mullvad.net/de/help/easy-wireguard-mullvad-setup-linux/)
but if you prefer OpenVPN, [there is also a good guide for that](https://mullvad.net/de/help/linux-openvpn-installation/)

I would however highly recommend for Wireguard since it's runs way faster, with less overhead and drains less battery opposed to OpenVPN